# File IO Default Param Question

Tags: c++, file-io

When opening a file, what is the default parameter to the file?

```
fstream  a1;
ifstream b2;
ofstream c3;

a1.open("randFile.txt");
b2.open("randFile.txt");
c3.open("randFile.txt");
```

Reference : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/open/

Comment: +1 since I always had this question and was lazy to check. Yet, LOL, you could check all the three in the site you linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**fstream:**

```
void open ( const char * filename,
            ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out );
```

So by default file will be opened both for input and output.

For ifstream and ofstream default value will be read-only and write-only correspondently (check method references for [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/open/) and [ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/open/))

Answer (score 1):

The function declaration states the default argument for the mode.  For `std::fstream::open`, it is:

```
void open(const char* filename,
          ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
                                    ^ default argument
```